# PHP Multiple User Login Form - Navigation to Different Pages Based on Login Credentials

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am trying to create a login page that will send the user to a different index.php page based on their login credentials. For example, should a user with the "IT Technician" role log in, they will be sent to "index.php", and if a user with the "Student" role log in, they will be sent to the "student/index.php" page.

I can't see what's wrong with my code, but it's not working... I'm getting the "wrong login credentials" message every time I press the login button.

My code for the user login page is here:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["manager"])) {
header("location: http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/index.php");
exit();
}
?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"]) && isset($_POST["role"])) {
$manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["username"]);
$password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password"]);
$role = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["role"]);
include "adminscripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM Users WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' AND role='$role' LIMIT 1");
$existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if (($existCount == 1) && ($role == 'IT Technician')) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $id = $row["id"];
    }
    $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
    $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
    $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
    $_SESSION["role"] = $role;
    header("location: http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/index.php");
} else {
    echo 'Your login details were incorrect. Please try again <a href="http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/index.php">here</a>';
    exit();
}
}
?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"]) && isset($_POST["role"])) {
$manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["username"]);
$password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password"]);
$role = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["role"]);
include "adminscripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM Users WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' AND role='$role' LIMIT 1");
$existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if (($existCount == 1) && ($role == 'Student')) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $id = $row["id"];
    }
    $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
    $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
    $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
    $_SESSION["role"] = $role;
    header("location: http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/student/index.php");
} else {
    echo 'Your login details were incorrect. Please try again <a href="http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/index.php">here</a>';
    exit();
}
}
?>
```

And the form that the data is pulled from is shown here:

```
<form id="LoginForm" name="LoginForm" method="post" action="http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/user_login.php">
  User Name:<br />
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="50" /><br />
  <br />

  Password:<br />
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="50" /><br />
  <br />

  Log in as:
  <select name="role" id="role">
    <option value="">...</option>
<option value="Head">Head</option> 
<option value="Deputy Head">Deputy Head</option> 
<option value="IT Technician">IT Technician</option> 
<option value="Pastoral Care">Pastoral Care</option> 
<option value="Bursar">Bursar</option> 
<option value="Secretary">Secretary</option> 
<option value="Housemaster">Housemaster</option> 
<option value="Teacher">Teacher</option> 
<option value="Tutor">Tutor</option> 
<option value="Sanatorium Staff">Sanatorium Staff</option> 
<option value="Kitchen Staff">Kitchen Staff</option> 
<option value="Parent">Parent</option> 
<option value="Student">Student</option>
</select><br />
  <br />

  <input type="submit" name = "button" id="button" value="Log In" onclick="javascript:return validateLoginForm();" />
  </h3>
</form>
```

Once logged in (and should the correct page be loaded, the validation code I have at the top of the script looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["manager"])) {
header("location: http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/user_login.php");
exit();
}

$managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["id"]);
$manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["manager"]);
$password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["password"]);
$role = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["role"]);

include "adminscripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM Users WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' AND role='$role' LIMIT 1");
$existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($existCount == 0) {
header("location: http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/index.php");
exit();
}
?>
```

Just so you're aware, the database table has the following fields: **id**, **username**, **password** and **role**.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks,
Zulu

Comment: Are you logging in as an `IT Technician`, using an account that actually has that role? Have you checked that your query actually returns a single row? Maybe you've got duplicated rows so it's returning a row count of 2 instead of 1.

Comment: I notice you are filtering against SQL injection - excellent! It's our favourite mistake here `:)`.

Comment: No duplicate rows, and the data is definitely in the table!

And thank you! Security is one of the main areas of the project :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic debugging situation, in which you can temporarily output intermediate data is see what is going wrong. There are a few improvements you can make to the code to make this easier.

- In your main login page, you appear to be connecting to the database twice, and doing a `SELECT` twice, and doing user input filtering twice. This is unnecessary. Reduce this to one block - it will make your code *much* more compact.
- Rather than putting code inside mysql functions, I think this is better:

  ```
  $sql = "
      SELECT id FROM Users
      WHERE
          username='$manager'
          AND password='$password'
          AND role='$role'
      LIMIT 1
  ";
  //echo $sql; exit();
  mysql_query($sql);
  ```

Now you can uncomment the `echo` line and see if the SQL is correct. Run it against the database manually to check, and then remove it when you're happy.

- Also, see how I indented the SQL string? It is much more readable this way.
- Use `header('Location: ...')` i.e. with an upper-case 'L'. Your way will work, but this way is more correct.
- After a redirect, always do `exit()`. This is because PHP will keep on running the script normally until the server realises that the user has disconnected - and you want to be kind to your server `:)`.
- You don't need to redirect to a fully-qualified URL. It is fine to redirect to `"/SchoolAdmin/index.php"`, which will save you *hard-wiring* your website address.
- You don't need to check all the `$_POST` vars before you do your database op. It's fine just to do this:

  ```
  if ($_POST) {
      // Form operation
  }
  ```

Much neater, and does the same thing!

- Addendum: rather than referencing values like 'IT Technician' in your code, use `define('ROLE_IT_TECH', 'IT Technician');` in a common include file. You can then reference it in your login code *and* in your login form, so you know you are always using the same value in all use-cases.
- Addendum 2: use `include_once` rather than `include`, so PHP ignores any repeated include statements.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As I've written to another contributor, I've tried this, and instead of getting the "wrong credentials" message, it's now just redirecting me to the login page. This (I think) means that I've now got to adjust the index page so it doesn't throw me out. ie it's logging me in correctly, then the page it navigates to is not recognising it... Any words of wisdom?! Zulu

Comment: Well, it seems that at the top of every page you are doing the login thing all over again. There's no need - just have a `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true` assignment in the login page, and then test for this at the start of every protected page. Much easier!

Comment: (By the way, it is generally not good practice on Stack Overflow to send the same message to all contributors - it's a bit like spam. Direct your particular questions to the user who most touched on your new issue. Just so you know!)

Comment: (Agreed with halfer...since I read all comments most the time anyway)

Comment: Thank you for your comments, and I've taken it on board :) Got myself in a pickle, so started from scratch (when I knew it worked by going to one place) and going through slowly. It seems that when I add an if statement within an if statement (as suggested above), this is when it loops round to the login page again! I'll keep at it! Thanks again

Comment: @ZuluIrminger - I think you were on track, tbh. One thing I would say is use version control of some kind (svn or git perhaps) so you can roll back really easily if you make a mistake. This will integrate with quite a few editors as well (Netbeans, Eclipse, etc) and is a great visual aid to development. Good luck, and once you've got further, ask another question! `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You have to restructure your if() statement where you check for successful login:

```
if (($existCount == 1) && ($role == 'IT Technician'))
```

The issue is that unless you login with the correct credentials AND the role of IT Technician you will see that "Incorrect Login" link.  You will never get to the code for Student or any other role.

One thing you can do is break apart the check for $existCount and $role.  Make sure they have logged in correctly.  If they have, then use a set of if() elseif() statements or a select/case to identify which $role they are are redirect to the appropriate page

pseudo code

```
if ($existCount == 1) {

    if($role == 'IT Technician') {
        header(location1);
    }
    elseif($role == 'Student') {
        header(location2);
    }
    elseif(etc...) {
        header(location3);
    }
}
```

Comment: For beginner programmers, I tend to advise that braces should always be used, as it is a source of common mistakes. Most style guidelines insist on it anyway (e.g. PEAR).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As I've written to another contributor, I've tried this, and instead of getting the "wrong credentials" message, it's now just redirecting me to the login page. This (I think) means that I've now got to adjust the index page so it doesn't throw me out. ie it's logging me in correctly, then the page it navigates to is not recognising it... Any words of wisdom?! Zulu

Answer (score 2):

You are hitting this section everytime your code runs because you are doing an if else

```
if (($existCount == 1) && ($role == 'IT Technician')) {
}
else {
     echo 'Your login details were incorrect. Please try again <a href="http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/index.php">here</a>';
exit();
}
```

Everytime your code is run and your role is not IT Technician, then you're sending an error message and stopping the application completely...no matter if it is a student, warthog, or no role.

Although there is a lot to improve, initially I'd suggest deleting the duplicated sections (IT Adminstrator vs Student) and instead retreiving the row from the database rather than letting the user submit it.

```
SELECT id FROM Users WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1

if ( count($sql) == 1 ) {
     if ( $sql['role'] == 'IT Adminstrator' ) {
          header('admin_url.php');
     } elseif ( $sql['role'] == 'Student' ) {
          header('student_url.php');
     };
};
```

Comment: @Gaurav Thank you very much for your answer. I've tried this, and instead of getting the "wrong credentials" message, it's now just redirecting me to the login page. This (I think) means that I've now got to adjust the index page so it doesn't throw me out. ie it's logging me in correctly, then the page it navigates to is not recognising it... Any words of wisdom?! Zulu